# Switching between data in detail view of parent table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I have a `UITableView` that navigates to a detail view when a `cell` is selected. Each `cell` and it's detail view passes through different data depending on which `cell` is selected. (On the storyboard it is one generic detail view)

For example I have three choices on the tableview: Page One, Page Two and Page Three. When I pick Page One for instance, there will be a button on the detail view which would allow me to go to the next page - Page Two, and if I selected Page Two the button would bring me to Page Three and so on.

I am not switching between different `UIViewControllers`, I am switching between the data that is passed through from the table view. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by pages? Do you mean table cells?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676880/switching-between-sibling-views-via-uinavigationviewcontroller  I have tried this but I think it might be to switch between different UIViewControllers? And yes I do mean table cells! @T_77

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: Yes, so on the storyboard it is one generic detail view. @T_77 It contains a text label and an image view so the info displayed depends on the cell that is selected

Comment: so you are saying detail view is different for each table cell. SO, after you go to detail view, there will be another button which takes you to another view? am i correct? and what is this another view?

Comment: Yes, the button will take you to the next view (the next item on the table) but it is the same detail view on the storyboard, does that make sense? @T_77

Comment: The data is stored in an array @T_77

Comment: simply send the data array to the detail view and load the data when you click on the button